External libraries are not functioning in the newly loaded HTMX page
I'm trying to load external scripts dynamically with HTMX, but the libraries don't work on the newly loaded page.

Can anyone provide a simpler solution than the one in my answer in
the answer section?
Also please explain why this answer is better
than the solution below.

Example Index page
<h1>Welcome to the Base Page</h1>
<button hx-get="sample_page" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#content">Load Table Page</button>
<div id="content">
    
</div>
<script defer src="persist@3.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="alpine@3.14.min.js"></script>
<script src="htmx.min.js"></script>

sample_page
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const gridOptions = {
            rowData: [{make: "Tesla", model: "Model Y", price: 64950, electric: true}], 
            columnDefs: [{field: "make"}, {field: "model"}, {field: "price"}, {field: "electric"}]
        }; 
        const myGridElement = document.querySelector('#myGrid'); 
        agGrid.createGrid(myGridElement, gridOptions);
</script>


Created in loadScript function in the base index page
<h1>Welcome to the Base Page</h1>
<button hx-get="sample_page" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#content">Load Table Page</button>
<div id="content">
 
</div>
<script defer src="persist@3.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="alpine@3.14.min.js"></script>
<script src="htmx.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function loadScript(src, callback) {
       const script = document.createElement('script');
       script.src = src;
       script.onload = callback;
       document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>

Call the loadScript in the new page and removed <script> tag
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script>
    loadScript('ag-grid-community.min.js', function() {
        const gridOptions = {
            rowData: [{make: "Tesla", model: "Model Y", price: 64950, electric: true}], 
            columnDefs: [{field: "make"}, {field: "model"}, {field: "price"}, {field: "electric"}]
        }; 
        const myGridElement = document.querySelector('#myGrid'); 
        agGrid.createGrid(myGridElement, gridOptions);});
</script>

To load multiple JavaScript files, I created another function
function loadScriptsSequentially(scripts, callback) {
         if (scripts.length === 0) {
            // All scripts are loaded, call the callback
            if (callback) callback();
            return;
         }

         // Load the first script
         const script = document.createElement('script');
         script.src = scripts[0];
         script.onload = function () {
            // Load the remaining scripts
            loadScriptsSequentially(scripts.slice(1), callback);
         };
         document.head.appendChild(script);
      }

Now, you can call the loadScriptsSequentially function like below
loadScriptsSequentially(["{{ static('js/ag-grid-community.min.js') }}"], function () {
  // rest of your codes
});

